# Mapping keystrokes to actual value? - Javascript

Tags: jquery, keyboard, javascript, keystroke

any cool libraries that you know about around? =)

Comment: There are, but can you specify what you'd like to do with the value once you have it? That might help with the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to tell exactly what you're asking, but if you're handling an event that gives you a *charCode*, such as **keypress**, you can use

```
var str = String.fromCharCode(event.charCode);

// or
var str = String.fromCharCode(event.which);
```

to get the value of the key that was pressed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/fromCharCode

Comment: In IE you bizarrely have to use the `keyCode` property to get the character code in the `keypress` event

Comment: @Tim Down, yes I actually forgot about that.  The OP tagged jQuery, though, so the event object should be consistent across browsers for jQuery bound events.

Answer (score 1):

This jquery [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) example pretty much does what you want.